# How can i install ubuntu without data loss

Tags: uninstall, windows-10, system

How can i install Ubuntu without data losing and only removing windows 10 partition [c drive] and not other partitions [d,e,f drives]

Comment: Run `sudo parted -l` and post output into question

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu and for your interest in this site.  Your question has been asked - and answered - previously.  Try searching Ask Ubuntu for something like "install ubuntu over windows partition" to locate relevant information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tutorial shows the steps at https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop .

When you get to [Allocate Drive Space](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#5)  choose Something Else. Pick the drive with Windows on it and tell the installer to erase the Windows system (C:) partition only, and not to install to any other drive or partition.

It is common for multiple drive letters to be assigned to space on one drive and the installation program will show you a map of 'partitions' like this. Read up on the program which handles this, [gparted](https://gparted.org/). https://www.pcworld.com/article/3050495/windows-10s-hidden-hard-drive-partitions-how-to-find-them-how-to-remove-them.html may also be helpful.

[image]